# Angular validator directive - validate method is never called

Tags: angular, validation, angular-validation

I have a following validation directive:

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator, ValidationErrors, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';
import { isNumber } from 'util';

@Directive({
    selector: '[minMaxValidator]',
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
        useExisting: MinMaxValidatorDirective,
        multi: true
    }]    
})

export class MinMaxValidatorDirective implements Validator {

    @Input() public minValue: number = null;
    @Input() public maxValue: number = null;

    constructor() { }

    validate(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors {
        let result: ValidationErrors = null;

        if (isNumber(c.value)) {
            if (this.minValue !== null && this.minValue > c.value) {
                result = { message: 'Value must be greater than ' + this.minValue };
            }

            if (this.maxValue !== null && this.maxValue < c.value) {
                result = { message: 'Value must be lower than ' + this.maxValue };
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
<input type="text" min-max-validator minValue="0" maxValue="1" [(ngModel)]="data.compression" />
```

Input renders, but validate method in validator is never called. I have no errors in console and validator is registered in app.module.ts

What am I missing?

Comment: Shouldn't it be minMaxValidator on your input tag ?

Comment: just change your selector `minMaxValidator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `minMaxValidator` (the selector for your directive) on your input field.

```
<input type="text" minMaxValidator minValue="0" maxValue="1" [(ngModel)]="data.compression" />
```